# What are the capabilities and limitations of using JSON to customize Wave Analytics Dashboard?

Tags: lightning, dashboard, einstein-analytics, analytics, salesforce-classic

As of the latest release guide, I could only find this [Summer ’17](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/bi_dev_guide_json.pdf) guide in regards to **Wave Analytics Dashboard**

But it is only the documentation of how to use JSON and what kinds of parameters can be added.

I have also browsed You tube videos without any success, finding out that there wasn't any visual material for this.

Is there a more high level guide on what level of **customization** JSON can achieve? For example, I know that the basic drag and drop has quite limited functionality. Wondering if JSON can scale the pie charts to any given size and be grouped together in 1 page like the image below?

[image]

Can someone with Wave Analytics Dashboard experience help to answer the question?

Thanks!

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two resources I know of that you'll find particularly helpful. First is the Einstein Analytics Group in the Success Community where these things are discussed all the time. Its a very active group. The other is the [Analytics REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_rest.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest/bi_resources_wave.htm) where you'll see what you can do with the JSON on various Wave Resources.